# slds-float blocks button onclick handler

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I'm trying to utilise slds-float (as slds-grid is a bit inefficient with space - I need the area under item on right to be useable).

However the button wrapped in `slds-float_right` does not seem to be receiving onclick events. Consider example:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-clearfix">
            <div class="slds-float_right">
                <lightning-button-icon
                        alternative-text="Delete settings"
                        icon-name="action:delete"
                        onclick={deleteSetting}>
                </lightning-button-icon>
            </div>
            <div>
                <lightning-accordion
                        class="override-accordion-border-top"
                        allow-multiple-sections-open="true">
                    <lightning-accordion-section
                            label="section a"
                            name="A">
                        baz
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </lightning-accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class Repro extends LightningElement {
    deleteSetting(evnet){
        alert(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float causes the lightning-accordion-section to cover the floating div. Instead, you should be placing the buttons in the action slot:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div slot="actions">
            <lightning-button-icon alternative-text="Delete settings" icon-name="action:delete" onclick={deleteSetting}>
            </lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
        <lightning-accordion class="override-accordion-border-top" allow-multiple-sections-open="true">
            <lightning-accordion-section label="section a" name="A">
                baz
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Note that the empty space you see is meant for a title area:

```
<h1 slot="title">My Title Here</h1>
```

*The link has been overridden by the new code.*

---

Edit:

Based on comments...

You can see that the button is actually covered by the section:

[image: Section covers button]

Which is what's causing the problem.

I can't seem to make SLDS behave correctly with this limitation. Instead, here's a compromise that doesn't use slds-grid:

## CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute-top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

## Template

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="absolute-top-right">
            <lightning-button-icon alternative-text="Delete settings" icon-name="action:delete" onclick={deleteSetting}>
            </lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
        <lightning-accordion class="override-accordion-border-top" allow-multiple-sections-open="true">
            <lightning-accordion-section label="section a" name="A">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                est laborum.
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </div>
</template>
```

You can see this in action [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/GO4USnwCOdzBwFSZh0m1/src/app.html).

Comment: Sorry about the card - this was used just to add white background and aid visibility. Please ignore it. Assume there's some other container.

Comment: @dzh Updated with example.